# FTP / New Firewalls

Tags: ftp, http-status-code-404, firewall, sonic

This is probably a long shot but...we recently upgraded from sonic to meraki firewalls on our network. We offer a public FTP site that is dmz'ed to our customers.

That FTP is a windows server 2008.

Prior to the meraki upgrade we had no trouble accessing that FTP site. Now, even internally the FTP site will either just time out or flat say the page cannot be found.

I'm just throwing that out there to see if there is something I can check or anything really.

I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **Configure > Firewall** and look at **Outbound rules**?  You probably need to add a rule under the **Protocol** field.  It allows you to allow connections through TCP, UDP, or any traffic.

More information about settings can be found here:
https://docs.meraki.com/display/MX/Firewall+settings

Comment: No problem.  Hope it helps. If it solves your question mark it as answered.  If it doesnt then just let me know and I'll try to help